# gnuplot - linear fit with x-errors

Tags: gnuplot

apologies if this is a very simple question, but I have searched everywhere and can't find a solution. I have a data file with three columns - x:y:xerrors. I want to fit a function f(x) to the data, by entering

```
f(x)=a*x+b
fit f(x) 'data' using 1:2:3 via a,b
```

But is this fit assuming that the entries in column 3 are y-errors, when actually they are x-errors?

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/patches/585/)?

Answer (score 2):

Change: `fit f(x) 'data' using 1:2:3 via a,b`

To: `fit f(x) 'data' using 1:2:3 with xerrorbars via a,b`

This treats the 3rd column as the uncertainty in `x` and computes an appropriate weight for the WSSR.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the fit assumes that the 3rd column is y-error if you specify
`using 1:2:3` else (if you do NOT specify) it assumes all weight equal to 1.

Meanwhile we wait the patch will be included in all the gnuplot distribution,
I can propose a Workaround: `# y=ax+b --> x=1./a*(y-b)`

> f(x)=a*x+b
>
> f2(x)=1./a * (y-b)
>
> fit f2(x) 'data' using **2:1**:3 via a,b
>
> plot 'data' with xerrorbar, f(x)

of course this changes the meaning of the *uncertainty* associated with a and b. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty).